# BeautifulSoup not reading documents correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape NBA players' statistics with the intention of running some machine learning on them, and I've found these 'printable player files' that have a bunch of statistics nice and neat. Unfortunately, I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse the html, and it's not working at all. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.nba.com/playerfile/ray_allen/printable_player_files.html'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

with open('ray_allen.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
    f.close()
```

Gives me a file that looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <!--no description was found-->
  <!--no title was found-->
  <!--no keywords found-->
  <!--not article-->
  <script>
   var site = "nba";
var page = "player";
  </script>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <script language="Javascript">
   &lt;!--
var flashinstalled = 0;
var flashversion = 0;
MSDetect = "false";
if (navigator.plugins &amp;&amp; navigator.plugins.length) {
    x = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"];
    if (x) {
        flashinstalle   d       =       2   ;   

           i   f       (   x   .   d   e   s   c   r   i   p   t   i   o   n   )       {   

               y       =       x   .   d   e   s   c   r   i   p   t   i   o   n   ;   

               f   l   a   s   h   v   e   r   s   i   o   n       =       y   .   c   h   a   r   A   t   (   y   .   i   n   d   e   x   O   f   (   '   .   '   )   -   1   )   ;   

           }   

       }       e   l   s   e   

           f   l   a   s   h   i   n   s   t   a   l   l   e   d       =       1   ;   

       i   f       (   n   a   v   i   g   a   t   o   r   .   p   l   u   g   i   n   s   [   "   S   h   o   c   k   w   a   v   e       F   l   a   s   h       2   .   0   "   ]   )       {   

           f   l   a   s   h   i   n   s   t   a   l   l   e   d       =       2   ;   

           f   l   a   s   h   v   e   r   s   i   o   n       =       2   ;   

       }   
[...]
```

Which then continues for another 3000+ lines before finishing with (The [...] is added by me):

```
[...]
   &lt;   /   b   o   d   y   &gt;   

   &lt;   /   h   t   m   l   &gt;
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

I also tried 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/allenra02.html' instead, and that one gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 9, in
>   
>       f.write(soup.prettify()) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb7' in position 6167: ordinal not in range(128)

Perhaps I should be using something else to parse html? Or are one of these problems easily fixable? What I read here seemed to indicate that using BeautifulSoup should make things easy for me rather than hard!

edit: The line:

```
print soup.prettify()
```

works for the 2nd page in the terminal, so there's something going on when it tries to write to file-- it's not a problem with BeautifulSoup

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: And what version of BeautifulSoup? I know the most recent one has some problems.

Comment: Wait. What makes you think this isn't working? What's the rest of the html file? That's what the start of the html page looks to me when I vew the source.

Comment: Python 2.7.3, BeautifulSoup 4.0.2-1.
Until the </script> tag at the end there, it's 3200+ lines of characters all separated by 3 spaces each, with symbols converted to their HTML entities (if that's the right word), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in BeautifulSoup 4.

I tried your code using BeautifulSoup 3 (as packaged in Ubuntu) by changing `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` to `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`, and it worked as expected. When I use v4 (running your code unchanged), I reproduced your problem. The bug seems to be in the parser rather than in `prettify` since printing the `soup` object shows the same issue.

Please file it as a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/. In the meanwhile, use version 3.

Answer (score 4):

This presents the same symptoms as [bug 972466](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/972466), which was fixed in 4.0.3. I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Beautiful Soup 4.