# spaced output beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrap the contents of a website. However in the output im getting unwanted spaces and hence im  not able to interpret this output. Im using a simple code :

```
 import urllib2
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html= 'http://idlebrain.com/movie/archive/index.html'
 soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(html).read())
 print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

OUTPUT::(output is very large so a small part of it in order to understand what problem im facing)

```
       <html><head><title>Telugu cinema reviews by Jeevi - idlebrain.com</title> 
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        </head><bodybgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="96%">
    <tr>
    <td align="left"> <img alt="Idlebrain.Com" height="63" src="../../image/vox_r01_c2.gif"width="264"/></td>
   <td><div align="right"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
      g   o   o   g   l   e   _   a   d   _   c   l   i   e   n   t       =       "   c   a   -   p   u   b   -   8   8   6   3   7   1   8   7   5   2   0   4   9   7   3   9   "   ;   

       /   *       r   e   v   i   e   w   s   -   h   o   r       *   /   

       g   o   o   g   l   e   _   a   d   _   s   l   o   t       =       "   1   6   4   8   6   2   0   2   7   3   "   ;   

      g   o   o   g   l   e   _   a   d   _   w   i   d   t   h       =       7   2   8   ;   

      g   o   o   g   l   e   _   a   d   _   h   e   i   g   h   t       =       9   0   ;   

      /   /   -   -   >   

     <   /   s   c   r   i   p   t   >   

     <   s   c   r   i   p   t       t   y   p   e   =   "   t   e   x   t   /   j   a   v   a   s   c   r   i   p   t   "   

     s   r   c   =   "   h   t   t   p   :   /   /   p   a   g   e   a   d   2   .   g   o   o   g   l   e   s   y   n   d   i   c   a   t   i   o   n   .   c   o   m   /   p   a   g   e   a   d   /   s   h   o   w   _   a   d   s   .   j   s   "   >   

     <   /   s   c   r   i   p   t   >   

                           <   /   d   i   v   >   

                   <   /   t   d   >   

           <   /   t   r   >   

    <   /   t   a   b   l   e   >   

    <   t   a   b   l   e       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   9   6   %   "       b   o   r   d   e   r   =   "   0   "       c   e   l   l   s   p   a   c   i   n   g   =   "   0   "       c   e   l   l   p   a   d   d   i   n   g   =   "   0   "   >   

             <   t   r   >       

                     <   t   d       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   1   2   8   "       v   a   l   i   g   n   =   "   t   o   p   "       a   l   i   g   n   =   "   l   e   f   t   "   >       

                           <   t   a   b   l   e       b   o   r   d   e   r   =   "   0   "       c   e   l   l   p   a   d   d   i   n   g   =   "   0   "       c   e   l   l   s   p   a   c   i   n   g   =   "   0   "       w   i   d   t   h   =   "   1   1   9   "   >   

     <   /   t   r   >   

    <   /   t   a   b   l   e   >   

     <   /   b   o   d   y   >   

     <   /   h   t   m   l   >   

           </script></div></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and it printed fine. Is this really the error case?

Comment: yea what did u do exactly, I havnt been able to rpint the output correctly , bt everything after "OUTPUT:" is the output that im geting and you can check the source code of the site that im trying to parse 'http://idlebrain.com/movie/archive/index.html'

Comment: @getitstarted: I can't reproduce your problem either.

Comment: Nor can I (although I'm using Python 2.7.3)

Comment: @Talvalin : Could you tell me what exactly ur doing. And ur output is not the same as what i have posted above ?

Comment: What versions of urllib2 and Beautiful Soup are you using? You can check by typing in `import urllib2` and `import bs4` then typing `print (MODULENAME.__version__)` for both urllib2 and bs4.

Comment: @Talvalin :for urllib2 version :2.7 and bs4:4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the parser as `html.parser`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(html).read(), 'html.parser')
```

Or you can specify the `html5` parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(html).read(), 'html5')
```

Haven't installed the `html5` parser yet? Install it from command-line:

```
sudo apt-get install python-html5lib
```

Also you may use the `xml` parser but you may see some differences in [multi-valued attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) like `class="foo bar"`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(html).read(), 'xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , but dont know the reason exactly. I installed virtualenv and ran my program inside it. and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of [BeautifulSoup not reading documents correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354521/beautifulsoup-not-reading-documents-correctly?rq=1), i.e. was caused by a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/972466) in BS 4.0.2.

That bug has been fixed in 4.0.3. You might want to check the output of

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
```

I suspect it's 4.0.2 for your system's BeautifulSoup, while it's 4.0.3 (or later) in your virtualenv. So if you want your code to run properly on your system, upgrade BeautifulSoup to a later version.