# Parsing a long html using BeautifulSoup failed with half parsed output

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I used the following script to parse the fund price of a particular fund:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page,resources = ghost.open('http://bank.hangseng.com/1/PA_1_1_P1/ComSvlet_MiniSite_eng_gif?app=eINVCFundDetailsOV&pri_fund_code=U44217')
page,resources = ghost.evaluate("agree()", expect_loading=True)
page,resources = ghost.evaluate("MM_changeview('eINVCFundPriceDividend')", expect_loading=True)
# ghost.capture_to("hangseng.png")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
soup
```

The output `soup` is OK for the first half, but the tag all turned in uppercase and BeautifulSoup cannot parse them, like the one below:

```
<td class="LightGrey" valign="TOP"><font class="CONTENT">22-07-2014</font></td><td class="LightGrey" valign="TOP"><font class="CONTENT">10.95000</font></td><td class="LightGrey" valign="TOP"><font class="CONTENT">11.39000</font></td><td class="LightGrey" valign="TOP"><font class="CONTENT">10.95000</font></td>
</tr>
 T R   V A L I G N = " t o p "   a l i g n = " c e n t e r " &gt; 
 T D   C L A S S = " L i g h t G r e y "   V A L I G N = " T O P " &gt; F O N T   C L A S S = " C O N T E N T " &gt; 2 1 - 0 7 - 2 0 1 4 / F O N T &gt; / T D &gt; T D   C L A S S = " L i g h t G r e y "   V A L I G N = " T O P " &gt; F O N T   C L A S S = " C O N T E N T " &gt; 1 0 . 9 6 0 0 0 / F O N T &gt; / T D &gt; T D   C L A S S = " L i g h t G r e y "   V A L I G N = " T O P " &gt; F O N T   C L A S S = " C O N T E N T " &gt; 1 1 . 4 0 0 0 0 / F O N T &gt; / T D &gt; T D   C L A S S = " L i g h t G r e y "   V A L I G N = " T O P " &gt; F O N T   C L A S S = " C O N T E N T " &gt; 1 0 . 9 6 0 0 0 / F O N T &gt; / T D &gt; 
 / T R &gt;
```

You can see the output becomes garbage after the date `2014-07-22`.

What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution from [spaced output beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046970/spaced-output-beautifulsoup?rq=1)

```
page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
```

Now it works perfectly.